# C : memcpy to the "end" of a buffer

Tags: c, buffer, memcpy

I got a giant buffer and I need to write strings and ints to it.

I know you can write to it using memcpy / memmove. But in that case, I'd have to offset each variable.

Example :

```c
int a = 10;
char *s = "hello world";
char buf[100];
memcpy(buf, a, 4);
memcpy(buf + 4, s, strlen(s))
```

As you can see I need to offset + 4 to the second memcpy for it to work.

I got tons of variables. I don't want to offset each one of them. Is it possible to do so ?

PS : the buffer is exactly the size of the sum of all variables

Comment: If you want to copy it into certain parts of the buffer then you need to offset. Not sure what alternative you are thinking of. I guess you can keep a pointer to the next position in the buffer to write to but that still requires moving the pointer after each write. It's not very clear what your exact goal is.

Comment: Put them all in a struct? What's the goal? Serialization?

Comment: @Passerby FIFO work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can keep the current offset in a separate variable and increase it for each value you copy in.

```
int a = 10;
char *s = "hello world";

char buf[100];
int offset = 0;

memcpy(buf + offset, &a, sizeof(a));
offset += sizeof(a);
memcpy(buf + offset, s, strlen(s))
offset += strlen(s);
```

This also has the advantage that you can reorder fields by moving pairs of lines around without having to renumber anything.

Comment: Haha that was exactly what I was doing. Guess there is nothing that can do that automatically. Thank you ! Closed*